# returned express err object doesn't contain err.message

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6

I have asked another question relating to error. Not sure if I should have edit that question.

Anyway, for the following code:

```
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.json({
    message: err.message,
    err // this err object doens't have err.message property
  });
  next();
});
```

I don't understand if this is a Node thing or Express thing.

Can someone please explain how and why this happens?

Shouldn't the `err` object when return contain all its properties?

Currently I am doing this to get around it:

```
res.json({
  err: Object.assign(err, { message: err.message })
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Shouldn't the `err` object when return contain all its properties?

With most JSON serializers, that will depend entirely on whether the properties are *enumerable*.

In the specification, the `Error` object's `message` property [is defined as non-enumerable](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-error-message), so it doesn't show up in the JSON.

I'm surprised to hear that your `assign` approach works, because according to the specification it should just write back to the existing property, which is non-enumerable and would remain so. That's what V8 does in Chrome 50:

```js
var err = new Error("the error");
console.log("err.message is enumerable? " + getPropDesc(err, "message").enumerable);
var obj = Object.assign(err, {message: "updated"});
console.log("obj === err? " + (obj === err)); // should be true
console.log("obj.message is enumerable? " + getPropDesc(obj, "message").enumerable);
console.log("JSON for err: " + JSON.stringify(err));
if (obj !== err) { // shouldn't be true
  console.log("JSON for obj: " + JSON.stringify(obj));
}

function getPropDesc(o, prop) {
  var desc;
  while (o) {
    desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(o, prop);
    if (desc) {
      return desc;
    }
    o = Object.getPrototypeOf(o);
  }
  return null;
}
```

I would expect *this* to work:

```
res.json({
  err: Object.assign({}, err, { message: err.message })
  // Note -----------^^^^
});
```

...but not what you've quoted. Perhaps the `err` object you're getting isn't an `Error` instance. `Error` was (in ES5 and earlier) notoriously difficult to subclass, so it may well be that the code you're using doesn't try to, instead doing something like this:

```
var err = Object.create(new Error("the error"));
```

**That** would result in the behavior you're seeing:

```js
var err = Object.create(new Error("the error"));
console.log("err.message is enumerable? " + getPropDesc(err, "message").enumerable);
var obj = Object.assign(err, {message: "updated"});
console.log("obj === err? " + (obj === err)); // should be true
console.log("obj.message is enumerable? " + getPropDesc(obj, "message").enumerable);
console.log("JSON for err: " + JSON.stringify(err));
if (obj !== err) { // shouldn't be true
  console.log("JSON for obj: " + JSON.stringify(obj));
}

function getPropDesc(o, prop) {
  var desc;
  while (o) {
    desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(o, prop);
    if (desc) {
      return desc;
    }
    o = Object.getPrototypeOf(o);
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: So can I conclude that when you do ```const err = new Error('errormsg') ``` it creates ```err``` object with non-enumberable ```err.message```, but if i do ```const err = new Error(); err.message="erromsg"```, the ```err.message``` will be enumerable?

Comment: @Alex: Actually, the `message` property on `Error` objects is always non-enumerable. I've updated the answer with details on that. If your `assign` thing is working, it sounds like a bug in the version of V8 in the NodeJS you're using (or alternately, the `err` object you're getting there isn't a true `Error` object). V8 in Chrome 50 doesn't make `message` enumerable when doing your `assign`.